# How can I use Font Awesome icons in an Office UI Fabric React icon button component?

Tags: reactjs, button, icons, font-awesome, office-ui-fabric

I'm using Office Fabric UI in React. I'd like to use Font Awesome icons on an [icon button](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/button) instead of the Fabric ones.

Can anyone show me how I'd do this?

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: No. I read after I asked the question that the included icons weren't licensed for anything except when used as part of MS Office apps, so I abandoned the plan to use it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been [raised](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/4913) on their github page and later added to their [documents](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Using-icons#registering-custom-icons).

Below is the copy&paste from their doc,
**registering icons**

```
import { registerIcons } from '@uifabric/styling';
import Icon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';    
registerIcons({
  icons: {
    'Home': <Icon icon={['fal', 'home']} />,
    'HomeSolid': <Icon icon={['fas', 'home']} />,
  }
});
```

**Using it**

```
import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

const IconTest = () => <Button iconProps={{ iconName: 'HomeSolid' }} />
```